# How to set if Edittext is empty . the sharedpreference won't store?

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I have a simple note activity ... from there the user inserts texts and can save or load them by two buttons ... but the problem that I have is ... 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4YOQ.png)

I don't know how to prevent not saving empty edittext because the empty box can still be saved which overwrites the saved texts . and then the user will lose the texts when tries to load the old texts.. if the you need any code please tell me ..

```html
    public static final String FILENAME="ShareDATA";
    public static final String KEYNAME="key";
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreference;
    EditText edittext;
    Button save,load;
    TextView tv3, texf;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_preference);

        texf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        texf.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "rrabar.ttf"));

        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textferk);
        tv3.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "rrabar.ttf"));


        edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        load=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);


        try{
            save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    sharedpreference=getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Editor editor=sharedpreference.edit();
                    editor.putString(KEYNAME, edittext.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();
                    edittext.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        try{

            load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sharedpreference=getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    edittext.setText(sharedpreference.getString(KEYNAME, "نووسینی نیشانه‌كراو بوونی نییه‌."));

                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception f) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), f.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: edittext.getText().toString().length() compare with 0

Comment: Thank you .. I'm gonna try this and let you know :)

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: I posted the code my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a check before you store the data

```
...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
        // store data
    }
    else {
        // show error message or something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help my friend :)

Comment: Hmm.. you accepted an answer that was posted 20 minutes later, which is basically the same but after you've posted your code

Comment: Sorry my mate..  I got your point and it's your right to say that .. I'm new to this website that is why it happened :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `Button` as default disabled in the xml something like `android:enabled=false`. After that put a `TextChangeListener` on the `EditText` and enable the `Button` if the text length is greater than zero e.g.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(count > 0) // enable button else disable;
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Check simple condition**

```
        if (!editText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        // store data
    } else {
        // show error message or something
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help my friend :)

Comment: I like to accept it but it's the right thing to accept Denny's answer as he helped first but Thank you very much again and have a great day :)

Comment: @Khamkhor ok Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (edittext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {

                    sharedpreference = getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Editor editor = sharedpreference.edit();
                    editor.putString(KEYNAME, edittext.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter something...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // Clear
                edittext.setText("");
            }
        });
```

> `String.trim()` method eliminates `leading` and `trailing` spaces from
>   string. Returns a `string` whose value is this string, with any leading and trailing `whitespace` removed.

Comment: Sorry my brother ... I'm new to this website  and  
I really like to accept your answer but it's the right thing to accept Denny's answer as he helped first but Thank you very much again and have a great day :)

Comment: No problem dear. Happy coding :)